# How to convert english date to Chinese and Korean

Tags: date, groovy

I have tried to implement locale for date. But it is working fine except for Chinese and Korean Language. For Chinese and Korean language, '??' is coming in the place of month.

Language: Groovy,grails 1.3.7

please see the code below

```
    Date from=new Date(params.from)
    Date to=new Date(params.to)+1

    //params.from and params.to is in english


    dateMap.from=from
    dateMap.to=to




   SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",locale)
   String fromDate
   String toDate
   fromDate=sdf.format(from)
   toDate=sdf.format(to)


   println "fromdate :"+fromDate
```

output is 
fromdate :09-??-2015

This is working fine for all other languages.

---

Please see below one more code i tried.

```
     locale=new Locale("zh","CN")

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatCN = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",          locale);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date temp = dateFormat.parse("05-Sep-2013");

    println "temp :"+temp
    String out=dateFormatCN.format(temp);
    println "out :"+out
```

output :
temp :Thu Sep 05 00:00:00 IST 2013
out :05-??-2013

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't just that your console doesn't support the appropriate characters?

Comment: yes, i tried in other systems as well. Same error exist. params.from :09 Aug 2015
params.to :09 Aug 2015

Comment: That just means the other consoles may have the same problem. It doesn't help that we don't know *anything* about your execution environment. Well you should find out whether the problem is the string or the display. For example, print out each character in `fromDate` as an *integer* and compare that with Unicode code charts. Additionally, this clearly isn't Java - it may well be Groovy, but it's not Java...

Comment: Also, try just printing whatever String means "August" in Chinese and/or Korean.

Comment: And as a general rule, it's better to copy/paste your actual code into your question, rather than to retype it and mess up most of the syntax.  Just in case the problem was something that you didn't accurately reproduce.

Comment: I have edited my question. Above code is the exact one i am using for converting. Is there any alternative to convert the date string into respective locale?

Comment: Looking at the timezone IST, I'm assuming you are working on a machine with English language pack. Java/Groovy has likely generated a correct output. But your console which prints out the text in a specific font (like Courier) cannot display the actual characters. Use a debug breakpoint and watch the variable, if the result is 05-九月-2013, it would work fine on your target machine with Chinese language packs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with your console.

I tried the below in [groovyConsole](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) and it worked

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def params = [to: '05-Sep-2013', from: '05-Sep-2013']

def locale=new Locale("zh","CN")
Date from=new Date(params.from) 
Date to=new Date(params.to)+1      //params.from and params.to is in english     

SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",locale) 
String fromDate  
String toDate    
fromDate=sdf.format(from)   
toDate=sdf.format(to)     
println "fromdate :"+fromDate​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Aseem. In that case what should i do to correct it ?

Comment: Just as others have said tell us about your execution environment. Which console are you printing this to? Are Chinese and Korean language packs installed?